# OWSLIB Python WCS GetCoverage does not work

Tags: python, error, wcs, owslib, getcoverage

I wrote a Python script in order to read a WCS with the module OWSlib:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from owslib.wcs import WebCoverageService
from owslib.util import Authentication
ldbv_url = 'https://geoservices.bayern.de/inspire-ows/v1/dop/oi/dls/wcs?'
wcs = WebCoverageService(ldbv_url, version='2.0.0',auth=Authentication(username='Test', password='Test'))
# Available Layer
print(wcs.contents.keys())
layer = 'dop20'
#GetCoverage Request
subset_bbox=(686995,687195,5346918,5347118)
#output=wcs.getCoverage()
output = wcs.getCoverage(identifier='dop20',Styles='fc',bbox=subset_bbox,format='image/tiff',crs='EPSG:25832', width=200, height=200)
```

However I get an error, as the `CoverageID` is wrongly set:

```
dict_keys(['dop20'])


Traceback (most recent call last):

File "r:\85\85_gemeinsam\rie\import_wcs.py", line 40, in <module>
output = wcs.getCoverage(identifier='dop20',Styles='fc',bbox=subset_bbox,format='image/tiff',crs='EPSG:25832', width=200, height=200)
File "C:\Users\rie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\owslib\coverage\wcs200.py", line 216, in getCoverage
u = openURL(base_url, data, method, self.cookies, auth=self.auth)
 File "C:\Users\rie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\owslib\util.py", line 210, in openURL
req.raise_for_status()
 File "C:\Users\rie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940,    in raise_for_status
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://geoservices.bayern.de/inspire-ows/v1/dop/oi/dls/wcs?version=2.0.0&request=GetCoverage&service=WCS&CoverageID=d&crs=EPSG%3A25832&format=image%2Ftiff&width=200&height=200&Styles=fc
```

The `CoverageId` must be `dop20`.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried `identifier=wcs['dop20'].id` which gives me `dop20`, if I print it.

The line `output = wcs.getCoverage(identifier=wcs['dop20'].id,Styles='fc',bbox=subset_bbox,format='image/tiff',crs='EPSG:25832', width=200, height=200)`
still gives me following error:

```
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://geoservices.bayern.de/inspire-ows/v1/dop/oi/dls/wcs?version=2.0.0&request=GetCoverage&service=WCS&CoverageID=d&crs=EPSG%3A25832&format=image%2Ftiff&width=200&height=200&Styles=fc
```

Again the CoverageID is set wrongly.

Comment: What does the print statement give you?

Comment: what does `print(list(wcs.contents))` give

Comment: The Prinz statement gives me dict_keys(['dop20'])

Comment: instead of `output = wcs.getCoverage(identifier='dop20'` try `output = wcs.getCoverage(identifier=wcs['dop20'].id`

Answer (score 1):

You have probably resolved this, but the solution is to provide a list of identifiers rather than the direct string of the variable you are seeking i.e:

```
wcs.getCoverage(identifier=[wcs['dop20'].id],
                Styles='fc',
                bbox=subset_bbox,
                format='image/tiff',crs='EPSG:25832', width=200, height=200)
```

This is a key difference between version 1.0.0 and 2.0.1, as 1.0.0 would accept a single string for the identifier.